# How to evaluate and do a network simulation for an already existing LAN?

Tags: switch, router, ethernet, lan

I'm an intern in a non-technological firm. it's a big company with 99 PCs and network printers. And they have the messiest Racks and LAN ever. I'm supposed to go through it, make a schema of the existing topology and make a simulation of a solution that can run the 6 floor building without the existing mess.
this is my first time doing anything like this. Are there any set of steps that I should follow in order to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the OODA loop, Observe, Orient, Decide, Act, which basically means you observe the current situation, come up with a game plan, decide on how to proceed, and act on that plan. Then you loop back up and start the cycle over. Try to break the project up into manageable chunks, for example what you can get done in a service window.

I'd start with Craig's 4 steps. It's important that you spend a lot of time getting to know "the proper way" of doing things in this industry. You won't get it right every time, but you'll spend less time reworking your own creation later on when you gain more experience.

When you have all the intel you can coerce out of your current setup, I'd clean up the L2 networks of every floor one by one. It's the most manual place to attack something like this, and it helps to have clean-ish racks when you break something by accident later. Don't try to get it perfect, just get it manageable for now.

Then attack the L3 backbone of the network. Tidy it up and get it running smoothly.

Then attack the server room last. By now you should have a pretty good idea of what you have and what you would like to have.

After this, you can start on the higher level stuff, like reorganizing the IP addressing scheme, add redundancy and better performance, the things that doesn't make the network function any better in a binary sense (connectivity/no connectivity) but improve the quality of the network service.

The progression of fixing a messy network is basically the same as troubleshooting it, start with L1 and move up in the model when you have the previous layer licked.

Answer (score 3):

This is an insanely broad question, but an outline is possible. Here's what I'd do if I was thrust into this situation.

1. Determine the goal. Am I "cleaning up" the mess without changing things. Meaning, literally organizing/cleaning up cabling, mounting, etc... while trying to "hold the line" with everything working as-is. Or am I "cleaning up" in the sense of getting ready for ongoing maintenance or future expansion. Locate the person who is responsible for this project and make sure they are on board.  (ie, who will be buying me things I say I need; software, labeling systems, cables, mounting hardware, tools)
2. Inventory. (Spend two work days reading about how to label and track things before lifting a finger.) Make an inventory of everything out to the wall jacks. Everything. Every cable, patch, rack, router, switch. Model numbers, serial numbers too. Everything. Get inventory/configuration-management software, or roll your own scheme if no money available. Label EVERYTHING as you along.
3. Possess. Gain administration ability on everything in inventory. Get in. Break in. (...or turn it off and then figure out who was responsible <- that's a joke. :) Integrate this admin knowledge into your CMDB/knowledge-base whatever.
4. Change. Pick something that qualifies as part of "this mess". Replace it with some industry standard thing/method that is better. Repeat.